# iOS 6 get Facebook access token with device account

Tags: facebook, ios5, ios6, access-token

The application I'm working on supports both iOS 5 and 6.
For iOS 5 I get an access token by using the FBSession object. The same thing works for iOS 6 but doesn't let me use the ACAccount that is already on the device and always asks the user to input email/password.

Since Facebook won't be updating their SDK for a couple of weeks to support this feature, and I don't have the option of waiting that long, I was wondering how do I get an access token using the accounts or social frameworks.

I've spent a few hours searching for an answer, but still no luck. So thanks to everybody in advance.

*EDIT*

Here is the code for getting the acces token with Facebook SDK 3.1+

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error){
                                      if (session.isOpen) {
                                          switch (status) {
                                              case FBSessionStateOpen:
                                                      // here you get the token
                                                      NSLog(@"%@", session.accessToken);
                                                  break;
                                              case FBSessionStateClosed:
                                              case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
                                                  [[FBSession activeSession] closeAndClearTokenInformation];
                                                  break;
                                              default:
                                                  break;
                                          } // switch
                                      }];
```

Comment: And what is your code for getting the FB access token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been fixed with Facebook SDK 3.1.

Comment: how? how are you getting the access token from the acaccount??

Comment: You don't get the access token from the account you get it from the session.

Comment: The session in the FB SDK? I dont see a session object in the Account framework.

Comment: You need to install the latest Facebook SDK, which works with the account framework if there is a local Facebook account. Otherwise it asks for login trough the browser or native Facebook app.